# Response.Redirect visual basic

Tags: macros, vb

Soy nuevo utilizando macros, me podrian indicar si esta es la manera correcta para abrir una pagina web:

```
Sub Reporte()

Response.Redirect ("http://www.microsoft.com")

End Sub
```

Me genara el siguiente error:

> Se ha producido el error 424 en tiempo de ejecución
>
> Se requiere objeto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Espero entender bien tu pregunta, es ¿desde un macro abrir una dirección web en HTML? Si es así entonces se podría hacer de esta manera.

Crear objeto , en este caso Internet Explorer y especificar la URL a navegar.
Es una forma, espero te pueda servir.

```
Sub navegar()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate "http://www.google.com"
End Sub
```

Comment: Una pregunta Silvestre, necesito usar una macro para abrir una pagina web que me pide usuarios y contraseña existe forma de que por medio de la macro yo le envie esos parametros y me de acceso a la siguiente pagina ?

Comment: Podrías observar el video de esta web, http://www.familycomputerclub.com/how-to-login-automatically-into-website-using-excel-vba.html no se sea algo similar a lo que pretendes realizar.